# Why does concurrent.futures executor map throw error when using with futures.as_completed after all the futures are complete?

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, python-multithreading

I am trying to send HTTP requests concurrently. In order to do so, I am using [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)

Here is simple code:

```
import requests
from concurrent import futures

data = range(10)


def send_request(item):
    requests.get("https://httpbin.org/ip")
    print("Request {} complete.".format(item))


executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=25)

futures_ = executor.map(send_request, data)

for f in futures.as_completed(futures_):
    f.result()
```

If I run it, I can see requests are sent asynchronously, which is exactly what I want to do. However, when all the requests are complete, I get following error:

```
Request 0 complete.
Request 6 complete.
...
Request 7 complete.
Request 9 complete.
Request 3 complete.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "send_thread.py", line 18, in <module>
    for f in futures.as_completed(futures_):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 219, in as_completed
    with _AcquireFutures(fs):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 146, in __enter__
    future._condition.acquire()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_condition'
```

This is quite strange error. Here `executor.map` seems to be problematic. If I replace map with following line, it works as expected.

```
futures_ = [executor.submit(send_request, x) for x in data]
```

What am I missing? Tried to find difference between two, but can't seem to understand what could cause above issue. Any input would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`Executor.map`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4ca0739c9d97ac7cd45499e0d31be68dc659d0e1/Lib/concurrent/futures/_base.py#L579-L592) does not return you a list of futures but a generator of results, so instead of:

```
futures_ = executor.map(send_request, data)
for f in futures.as_completed(futures_):
    f.result()
```

you should run:

```
results = executor.map(send_request, data)
for r in results:
    print(r)
```

Comment: I see, thank you very much. That raises another question: wouldn't that block if first request in that generator takes longer than others (whereas `futures.as_completed` processes as they complete)?

Comment: @chhantyal, you are correct, it blocks to return results in the same order corresponding futures were passed (to mimic builtin `map` function). If you need `futures.as_completed` behaviour, `Executor.map` is not appropriate.

Comment: Put a word, `concurrent.futures` is definitely not a proper way to send HTTP requests concurrently. You may actually want `aiohttp` lib.

Comment: @skovorodkin #TIL something interesting. Thank you again.

Comment: @Sraw you are right. However, above request is simple example. I am more looking into making IO calls faster in synchronous codebase, thus can't really use aiohttp.